# How to insert array contents into another array?

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I am trying to create a method in Dafny that lets me enter the contents of one array into another.
For instance, given Array1= [1,2,3], Array2 = [6,7,8,9,0], and index = 1, the output array would be [1,6,7,8,9,0,2,3] as the method inserts the contents of Array2 to Array1 given an insertion index.

The code is listed below:

```
method insertArrayIntoIndex(a: array<int>, index: int, add_these: array<int>) returns (result: array<int>)
    requires 0 <= index < a.Length;
    ensures result.Length == a.Length + add_these.Length;
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < index ==> a[i] == result[i];
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < add_these.Length ==> add_these[i] == result[i + index];
    ensures forall i :: index <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == result[i + add_these.Length];
{
    result := new int[a.Length + add_these.Length];

    // copy first part in
    var pos := 0;
    while (pos < index)
        invariant 0 <= pos <= index
        invariant 1 <= pos < index ==> result[pos-1] == a[pos-1]
    {
        result[pos] := a[pos];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }

    // copy in the addition
    pos := 0;
    while (pos < add_these.Length)
        invariant 0 <= pos <= add_these.Length
        invariant 1 <= pos < add_these.Length ==> result[index + pos-1] == add_these[pos-1]
    {
        result[index + pos] := add_these[pos];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }

    // copy the last part in
    pos := index;
    while (pos < a.Length)
        invariant index <= pos <= a.Length
        invariant index < pos < a.Length ==> result[pos-1 + add_these.Length] == a[pos-1]
    {
        result[pos + add_these.Length] := a[pos];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble writing the proper loop invariants to get the code working. I've tried adding assertions at the end of each section to prove each part is working as shown below but I'm not sure why they are failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also added additional assertions inside the first section but they all seem to pass which confuses me on why the assertions outside fail.

```
method insertArrayIntoIndex(a: array<int>, index: int, add_these: array<int>) returns (result: array<int>)
    requires 0 <= index < a.Length;
    ensures result.Length == a.Length + add_these.Length;
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < index ==> a[i] == result[i];
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < add_these.Length ==> add_these[i] == result[i + index];
    ensures forall i :: index <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == result[i + add_these.Length];
{
    result := new int[a.Length + add_these.Length];

    // copy first part in
    var pos := 0;
    while (pos < index)
        invariant 0 <= pos <= index
        invariant 1 <= pos < index ==> result[pos-1] == a[pos-1]
    {
        result[pos] := a[pos];
                assert result[pos] == a[pos];
                assert pos >1 ==> result[pos-1] == a[pos-1];
                assert forall i :: 0 <= i < pos ==> result[i] == a[i];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }
        assert forall i :: 0 <= i < index ==> a[i] == result[i];

    // copy in the addition
    pos := 0;
    while (pos < add_these.Length)
        invariant 0 <= pos <= add_these.Length
        invariant 1 <= pos < add_these.Length ==> result[index + pos-1] == add_these[pos-1]
    {
        result[index + pos] := add_these[pos];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }
         assert forall i :: 0 <= i < add_these.Length ==> result[index + i] == add_these[i];

    // copy the last part in
    pos := index;
    while (pos < a.Length)
        invariant index <= pos <= a.Length
        invariant index < pos < a.Length ==> result[pos-1 + add_these.Length] == a[pos-1]
    {
        result[pos + add_these.Length] := a[pos];
        pos := pos + 1;
    }
        assert forall i :: index <= i < a.Length ==> result[add_these.Length + i] == a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny uses loop invariant to reason about loops. Let's understand what
this entails.

Let's say you have written following loop

```
   idx := 0;
   while idx < a.Length
     invariant 0 <= idx <= a.Length
   {
      a[idx] := 1;
      idx := idx + 1;
   }
```

After loop, facts that are available to dafny to reason about rest of
program is `0 <= idx <= a.Length && idx >= a.Length` (second part is
loop termination condition). Inside loop, you can add `assert a[idx] == 1`
after assignment and it will verify. But
`assert forall m :: 0 <= m < a.Length ==> a[m] == 1`
after loop will n't verify as there is no invariant to prove this fact.

Let's say we want to prove that all elements of array is equal to 1
and we write following program

```
   idx := 0;
   while idx < a.Length
     invariant 0 <= idx <= a.Length
     invariant 1 <= idx <= a.Length ==> a[idx-1] == 1
   {
      a[idx] := 1;
      idx := idx + 1;
   }
```

Facts that is available to dafny after loop is
`0 <= idx <= a.Length && 1 <= idx <= a.Length ==> a[idx-1] == 1 && idx >= a.Length`.
Using above, it is not possible to arrive that
`assert forall m :: 0 <= m < a.Length ==> a[m] == 1` . In fact it is  possible only
to prove last element is equal to 1.

We need to ask dafny to remember using forall.

```
   idx := 0;
   while idx < a.Length
     invariant 0 <= idx <= a.Length
     invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < idx ==> a[m] == 1
   {
      a[idx] := 1;
      idx := idx + 1;
   }
```

After loop, fact that are available to dafny is
`forall m :: 0 <= m < idx ==> a[m] == 1 && idx >= a.Length && 0 <= idx <= a.Length`.
Now it is possible to prove `forall m :: 0 <= m < a.Length ==> a[m] == 1`

Taking care of these, this is how you can verify your insert function

```
method insert(a: array<int>, idx: int, b: array<int>)
  returns (r: array<int>)
  requires 0 <= idx < a.Length
  ensures r.Length == a.Length + b.Length
  ensures forall m :: 0 <= m < idx ==>  r[m] == a[m]
  ensures forall m :: 0 <= m < b.Length ==>  r[idx + m] == b[m]
  ensures forall m :: idx <= m < a.Length ==>  r[b.Length + m] == a[m]
{
  var i := 0;
  r := new int[a.Length + b.Length];

  while i < idx
    invariant 0 <= i <= idx
    invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < i ==>  r[m] == a[m]
  {
    r[i] := a[i];
    i := i + 1;
  }

  if b.Length != 0 {
    i := 0;
    while i < b.Length
      invariant 0 <= i <= b.Length
      invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < i ==> r[idx + m] == b[m]
      invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < idx ==>  r[m] == a[m]
    {
      r[idx + i] := b[i];
      i := i + 1;
    }

  }

  i := idx;
  while i < a.Length
    invariant idx <= i <= a.Length
    invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < idx ==>  r[m] == a[m]
    invariant forall m :: 0 <= m < b.Length ==>  r[idx + m] == b[m]
    invariant forall m :: idx <= m < i ==>  r[b.Length + m] == a[m]
  {
    r[b.Length + i] := a[i];
    i := i + 1;
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please replace "∙" by "::", "≔" by ":=" and "⟹" by "==>" in your code? You must be using Emacs, but these characters are not good for the code to be parsed in VSCode. That would make your solutions more easily verifiable for anyone. Thanks

Comment: Now I can upvote ^^